# getting neat upload demo progress bar working

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, file-upload, neatupload

I would like to get this control called NeatUpload from codeplex working on my web app.

I have downloaded the latest binary and the source code.

And I have configured web.config

And I have copy pasted the code from the demo page file and code behind file.

It compiles and runs and it does post to the server but doesn't show the progress bar.

I am using vs2010 with framework v4.0.

Did anyone have similar problem and got this working?

Appreciate any help in advance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have just spent all morning getting a simple single file upload working, so I appreciate there are some gaps in the basic documentation. Well, maybe not gaps, ambiguities. :o)

Here is what I did:

1. Download the bin release from Codeplex
2. Copy the NeatUpload folder from that into your application root *[1]*
3. Alter the web.config to add in the system.web/httpModules entry:

   `<add name="UploadHttpModule" type="Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.UploadHttpModule, Brettle.Web.NeatUpload"/>`
4. AND the system.webServer/modules entry:

   `<add name="UploadHttpModule" type="Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.UploadHttpModule, Brettle.Web.NeatUpload" preCondition="managedHandler"/>`

Then I have a very simple usercontrol to set up the upload:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="nup" Namespace="Brettle.Web.NeatUpload" Assembly="Brettle.Web.NeatUpload" %>
<div class="control_container cc_document_upload">
<nup:InputFile id="FileUploader" runat="server" />
<br/>
<nup:ProgressBar id="UploadProgress" Url="~/NeatUpload/Progress.aspx" Triggers="UploadButton" Inline="true" runat="server" />
<br/>
<asp:Button id="UploadButton" Text="Upload" runat="server" />
</div>
```

This is working for me.

*[1]* 2: This is the bit that I went wrong with as I was copying it into a plugins subfolder to keep things tidy. It MUST be the application root; a quick look through the source reveals what looks like some hardcoded paths. Before I moved it to the root I got the same behaviour as you - posting, but no progress.